# Is it possible to copy a profile?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, joomla

I created a 'Membership Info' profile but now realise that, because I have diferent membership types with different qualifications, the information I need to collect will not be completely the same. Can I copy the existing profile and edit the copies to make a different version for each membership type? (Instead of recreating the whole thing from scratch each time).

Comment: Thank you, everyone who responded. I had to resort to re-creating the necessary profile variations from scratch. Having the ability to duplicate profiles would be especially useful. Particularly when you have one with many fields that needs, say, four variations to it so from the original one you could make three copies and just add or delete specific fields that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can copy a Profile: when on the screen that lists the profiles on your site -> on the very right -> click more -> and select Copy Profile

Comment: First thing I thought of. On my system the only options are:
Preview, Disable or Delete.
I am running CiviCRM version 4.7.15 on Joomla 3.7.4

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to Copy Profiles for profiles that are used for Contacts (and possibly other entities). It is not currently possible to do this for Profiles using Membership fields.

I don't know why and thought I had asked one of the Fuzion team to take a look at this so it may be on a list to fix, or in JIRA, but not spotting it just now.

Comment: Ah - did not know that! Thanks Pete.